# how is registerObserver in ContentResolver is different from the one in SqliteCursor ?

Tags: android

I am having trouble understanding this.

From my research what SqliteCursor does is store the observer in a list .

When this call is made on ContentResolver

getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newuri, null);

My registered observer receives the notification ,implies that ContentResolver is using the same list of observers as SqliteCursor.

So ,they both does the same thing or am I missing something here ?.